# how to auto detect new entries from database in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a website and an app. exclusively for user entries. when consumers register using a mobile app. Without refreshing the page, I need to retrieve the new user info from my web app.

How can I tell whether my database's users table has a new entry? Moreover, I don't want to reload the page.

The web app is written in Django 3.2, and I use the Django Rest framework for APIs to allow users to sign up from the mobile app. Because I'm using numerous threads, I can't use ajax to submit requests regularly to check the DB status for new entries because it will be slow. If possible, I want to use a signal to resolve this.

Comment: you can use some Javascript/Ajax to get informations periodically from the DB through DRF APIs and automatically update html data (no page refresh needed)

Comment: how can send an ajax request? how do I know there is a new entry in DB.
if I use interval so there will be a problem because there are already multiple threads are running on my web, I can t send ajax requests to check DB status for new entries. it will be slow and a bad practic as well